# >>regex match<< how to capture 'ab' only from content like 'aab'

Tags: java, regex

we got some content like this:
`state 1rd court house, state state 2nd court house`

what we want is `state xxx court house`

we have try lookahead/lookbehind like this:
`(?=state).*?(?<=court house)`

but this regex extract `aab` like content just like `ab` kind content

how can i extract only `ab` from a string like `aab`

which means `start with something, but the capture content do not contains it`

**update**

> sorry for the poor description
>
> what i want to match is `state 1rd court house` and `state 2nd court house` and not match `state state 2nd court house`?
>
> which means if `state state 2nd court house` i'd like extract the rear part `state 2nd court house` ignore the first `state` appear in the content.

Comment: Your lookaheads and lookbehinds are on the wrong sides, for one. Right now they’re looking into the capture, but you want to look out of the capture by placing the lookbehind `(?<=` *before* it and the lookahead `(?=` *after*.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that [tag:regex] tag says: "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.". Also, please make a specific example of what you want to match and what you don't want to match, without using metasyntactic variables like `xxx`, `aab` or `ab` (unless they are a literal part of your example). Do you want to match `state 1rd court house` and `state 2nd court house` and not match `state state 2nd court house`?

Comment: @Amadan sorry about the poor description,  update the question right now

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you simply want to capture everything before court house including "court house".

**Regular Expression**

```
state(?<whatYouWant> [0-9].*?court house)*
```

**Test String**

```
state 1st court house, state state 2nd court house
```

> match 1: `state 1st court house`
>   Group `whatYouWant`: `1st court house`
>   match 2: `state 1st court house`
>   Group `whatYouWant`: `2nd court house`

I assumed that the look back will stop when you hit a digit ex: "1", "2". If my assumption is wrong, send me the data that breaks the Regex.

Comment: first, thx for ur answer and sorry for my poor english, u have get part of my question. what i really want may describe as follow: **full content**: `state 1st court house, state state 2nd court house`, **what i want**: `state 1st court house` and 'state 2nd court house', in other words, i want strings start with `state` and end with `court house`, but when it comes to content like `state state 2nd court house` i don't want match the first `state` but only the rear part `state 2nd court house`.

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification. Let me update my answer for you.